# Import Error: No Module found named TestLIb

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python file from the telnet session

Steps:

**Dailyscript.py**

1. Telnetting in to montavista
2. from the telnet session I am trying to run another python file "python sample.py"

**sample.py**

1. Importing TestLib (in this file)

But, when I run directly form my linux box, it is running fine.

Is there any thing I need?

Comment: So is TestLib installed in the remote system? (And you should really consider using ssh rather than telnet.)

Comment: provide some code, please

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that TestLib.py isn't in your working directory. Make sure your Dailyscript.py sets its directory to wherever you ran it from (over SSH) before executing `python sample.py`.

Also, if you have SSH access, why aren't you just using SSH?

Comment: I TestLib is in my local directoy only. This dir path i am exporting in the python path. /home/user/sw/test/env/TestLib.py in the Dailyscript.py i am exporting this this path . my.Host.write("export /home/user/sw/test/env/TestLib.py \n")
Eventhough i am getting the above error.

Comment: @user1741573 `export /home/user/sw/test/env/TestLib.py` isn't a valid command. You probably need to do `cd /home/user/sw/test/env/TestLib.py`.